# Are there any versioning for kubernetes ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I want to know if there is versioning for ingress config similar to what we have in deployments. Suppose there is a misconfiguration I would like to revert to the previous config.
I would like to understand about `generation` in ingress YAML config.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-match: 'new-nginx: header("foo", /^bar$/)'           #Canary release rule. In this example, the request header is used.
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/service-weight: 'new-nginx: 50,old-nginx: 50'                #The route weight.
  creationTimestamp: null
  generation: 1
  name: nginx-ingress
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/ingresses/nginx-ingress
spec:
  rules:                                                        ##The Ingress rule.
  - host: foo.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: new-nginx
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
      - backend:
          serviceName: old-nginx
          servicePort: 80
        path: /
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes does not offer this natively, and neither does a management tool like Rancher.

If you want to do this, you need an infra-as-code tool, like Terreform, ansible, etc.  The config files for these can be versioned in a repo.

Even without those, you can independently export a give ingress yaml, and commit it to a repo.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different way to look at a solution - you could use gitOps. I mean that you could put all your yaml's in a git repo, install ArgoCD on your cluster and then simply let ArgoCD do the syncing for you. The moment you realised you've messed something up in a yaml file, just revert the commit in the git repo. That way you maintain history and get a graceful non-opinionated solution.